# I keep getting the error: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".user-profile-link"}

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, element

I keep getting the error: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".user-profile-link"} - Everythin works Ok except for this error and I have tried to search for a solution with no success. Please help. Note that in the code I pasted below, I replaced my real username and password with "my_github_username" and "my_github_password" respectively.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://github.com/")


browser.maximize_window()
signin_link = browser.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Sign in")
signin_link.click()

username_box = browser.find_element(By.ID, "login_field")
username_box.send_keys("my_github_username")
password_box = browser.find_element(By.ID, "password")
password_box.send_keys("my_github_password")
password_box.submit()

profile_link = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "user-profile-link")
link_label = profile_link.get_attribute("innerHTML")
assert "my_github_username" in link_label

browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you print out the HTML by using the `print(driver.page_source)`, so it is easier for people to help you investigate and you would get more efficient support?

I believe the potential root cause would be that the portion of your code gets executed before the element that you seek finishes loading.
Perhaps, try adding `time.sleep(5)` or if you would want to be more advance, you can use `WebDriverWait`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://github.com/")


browser.maximize_window()
signin_link = browser.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Sign in")
signin_link.click()

# add some wait time here by using either `time.sleep(5)` or WebDriverWait
# time.sleep(5)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#login_field')))

username_box = browser.find_element(By.ID, "login_field")
username_box.send_keys("my_github_username")
password_box = browser.find_element(By.ID, "password")
password_box.send_keys("my_github_password")
password_box.submit()

# add some wait time here by using either `time.sleep(5)` or WebDriverWait
# time.sleep(5)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.user-profile-link')))

profile_link = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "user-profile-link")
link_label = profile_link.get_attribute("innerHTML")
assert "my_github_username" in link_label

browser.quit()
```

Comment: Using wait solved my issue. Thanks so much. You are right. The potential root cause was that the portion of my code gets executed before the element that I seek finishes loading.

Comment: @VincentOke Since you are satisfied with my answer, please kindly upvote. Thank you.